# Changing Month (from Number) to Full Month Name in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure if I missed it explained elsewhere but I need some help changing the month number (ex. 1, 2, 3) to month name (ex. January, February, March).

Currently, the graph prints the number of the month on the x-axis and I would like for it to show the name of the month.

I did try a few items but kept getting null in the column.

Below is my current code:

```
install.packages("Stat2Data")
library(Stat2Data)
data("CO2Hawaii")

select(CO2Hawaii)

hawaiiGraph <- 
  ggplot(
    data = CO2Hawaii, 
    aes(
      x = Month, 
      y = CO2)
    ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(group = Year)
    ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 55, hjust = 1)
    ) +
  ggtitle("CO2 Levels in Hawaii Over Time")
  
hawaiiGraph
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: `Stata2Data` is not a CRAN package, where can we find it? As for the question, try `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B-%Y")`.

Comment: Sorry, you have to install the package. When I used your code, I kept getting error messages like: Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Comment: OK, but the package name is `Stat2Data`, not `Stata2Data`. I have edited the question correcting the typo.

Comment: Sorry! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

The `Month` is a numeric column so the trick is to label the `x` axis with the built-in variable `month.name` with breaks vector `1:12`. This is done in `scale_x_continuous`.
Note also that it's not necessary to load a package to access one of its data sets.

```
library(ggplot2)

data("CO2Hawaii", package = "Stat2Data")

hawaiiGraph <- ggplot(
  data = CO2Hawaii,
  mapping = aes(
    x = Month, 
    y = CO2)
) +
  geom_line(
    aes(group = Year)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq_along(month.name), 
    labels = month.name
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 55, hjust = 1)
  ) +
  ggtitle("CO2 Levels in Hawaii Over Time")

hawaiiGraph
```

[image]

If the month name is too long, `month.abb` gives you the same result but with an abbreviated month name (i.e `Jan` instead of `January`.